# How to get type of profile of a post owner in Facebook Graph Api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am retrieving posts using facebook api. Adding a field from gives the detials of post owner. But according to Documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/profile) the profile may be a user/page/group. How can i get only the posts by page in the same api call.?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible for posts request. Usually it is done by using "filtering" parameter. But as per documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/page/feed, "filtering" is deprecated for this request.